# javascript pop-up window with clickable image

Tags: javascript, image, popup, window, clickable

I have a pop-up window (in Javascript) in which I would like to include a button hidden in an image.

So if the user clicks on the image the action should be performed. In HTML this is easy, but I don't know how to do this in Javascript.
Thanks for any help.

What I know is how to do it with TEXT. This is how I do it:

```
document.write('<input type="button" value="F e r m e r" onClick=\'window.close()\' class="button" onmouseover="this.className=\'buttonon\'" onmouseout="this.className=\'button\'" style="width: 100px;">');
```

Comment: `<button type="button" title="Fermer" onclick="window.close()" ><img src="..."></button>`

Answer (score 1):

You can just set `background-image` of button in *CSS* as you're probably going to style it anyway.

```js
document.write('<button type="button" class="image-button" onclick="myFunction()">')    

function myFunction() {
  console.log("I love Malamuts");
}
```

```css
.image-button {
  background-image: url("https://www.psy.pl/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/shutterstock_375206839-864x575.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```